# SQL multiply by AVG

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a column ([A]) with some numbers - say A1, A2, A3.... And and I need to have a second one ([B]) which is a result of multiplying first one with average of all numbers there - e.g.

```
B1=A1*(A1+A2+.....+An)/n
B2=A2*(A1+A2+.....+An)/n
```

and so on. MS SQL Server 2016

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT a * AVG(a) OVER () AS b
FROM t
```

- `AVG(a)` is identical to `SUM(a) / COUNT(a)`
- `AVG(a) OVER ()` is identical to `SELECT AVG(a) FROM t`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select A as A, A * (select sum(A) from tbl) / (select count(A) from tbl) as B
from tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use window function

```
select A ,A*( sum(A) over()/count(A)over()) as B
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a derived table (the sub-query), where you calculate `sum(A)` and `n`. `CROSS JOIN`.

```
select t1.A * t2.sumA / t2.n
from tablename t1
cross join (select sum(A) as sumA, count(*) as n from tablename) t2
```